# How to use an mvn module of CDI beans in a jar module in Weblogic?

Tags: java, maven, ejb, weblogic, cdi

I have an mvn module which contains only CDI beans. I want to inject some named beans from that module into another bean in another module. So I add it to the dependencies in its pom.xml. In my main ear pom.xml I define this as a jarModule. I believe Weblogic won't recognize my CDI beans since they are not a ejbModule (I might be wrong). How could I overcome this?

It all works when I add a dummy EJB to my module which contains the CDI beans, and define the module as ejbModule, but this is not a nice solution.

Comment: Do you need it to be an EAR? Can it be a WAR?

Comment: I need in an EAR, it is an existing project

Comment: With EAR you are usually bumping into visibility issues (as defined in JEE spec). Could you share the complete EAR structure? Where is this 'mvn module' located and is it a simple jar?